# Transpose a column with respect to next column

Tags: awk, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a  file (file1.vcf) as like this

```
chr1 254 . A . 80 . . xxxx xxxxx
chr1 255 . T . 80 . . xxxx xxxxx
chr1 554 . G C 80 . . xxxx xxxxx
chr1 554 . A . 80 . . xxxx xxxxx
chr1 754 . G A 80 . . xxxx xxxxx
```

Based on the fourth and fifth column value I need to create a new file as like this

```
>file1
ATCAA
```

It is important that if some value is on fifth column forth one have to replace with that. I tried with following awk and transpose

```
 awk '{if ($5==".") print $4 
else print $5}'
```

but I could able to find a solution for outputting as expected

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly edit your question with your efforts and let us know then.

Comment: Algorithm looks really simple, basically: if (value of 5th column is a dot) output(4th column) else output(5th column).

Comment: Look up `printf` in the awk man page.

Comment: Try `awk '{if ($5==".") s=s $4; 
else s=s  $5; }END{ print s }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s", ($5=="."?$4:$5)}' file
ATCAA
```

if you need a newline at the end, add `END{print ""}`